# Playing VideoJS in Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, video.js

I had Fancybox setup to work with VideoJS v.2.x.x but after they re-designed the code in v.3.x, `setupAllWhenReady`. I used to be able to do this

```
jQuery(this).fancybox({
    'onComplete': function () {
        jQuery("#fancybox-inner").css({ 'overflow': 'hidden' });
        VideoJS.setupAllWhenReady();
    }
});
```

Now the video still plays in Chrome, I guessing because Chrome natively supports HTML videos but in Firefox it is not playing at all. First comes up the poster img and and x in the middle and when you click on it, it goes into an endless loading wheel.

Comment: Any errors in js console?

Answer (score 0):

This is the new way to initialized a video.js player, after it gets dynamically added to the page:

```
var myPlayer = _V_("example_video_1");
```

example_video_1 is the ID of the `<video>` tag

Then you can use myPlayer for other API functions like play() or pause()